# What exactly is a Cloud Firewall?

Tags: security, firewall, cloud

Recently I hear a lot of the buzz word "Cloud" and I have even heard of Cloud firewall. But what I was looking for is if I implement Infrastructure as a service (IaaS) as a private cloud using eucalyptus and create groups (using euca-tools) will this be secure enough?
 Also I came across a thread in a forum where a user installed pfSense in the VM's. Is this meaningful? 
Actually I am an intern and I was asked to look into access controls in Cloud.  I was also asked to install a tool (developed by my company) which provides fine grained access controls by pushing IPtables, this is done centrally.  I am planning to deploy this in VM's. 
 But if the euca-groups is secure enough what I am doing isnt just a waste of time? I am very confused on this.

Comment: "Cloud" and "Cloud Firewall" are buzzwords that have no formal meaning. "Cloud Firewall" could mean a good solution like a hardware firewall, IDS, etc. all in place, or it could just mean they have iptables on all their VM images.

Comment: @ceejayoz: So its perfectly makes sense when I install pfSense or any other host-based-firewall on the VMs inside the cloud. Which is nothing but offers another layer of security. Right? Actually I didnt get an answer to that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cloud firewall is basically a system which filters incoming (and possible outgoing) traffic for your, as a local firewall would.

All your public traffic has to go through the cloud firewalls provider. So you have to deny all the traffic on your local firewall which does not go through the "cloud firewall" (otherwise the attacker is bypassing the firewall setup).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This partly answers my Question. What I was looking for is installing a host based firewall in the VMs is useful?

Comment: Personally, i would not install a productive firewall in a virtual maschine, because an attacker could compromise not only the fw system but the host system too.